# Is it a function in Excel to extract a date diff from specific reference?

Tags: excel, date

I'm searching a way to extract a date and compute number of days from a specific reference like this:

```
"C20200923.01"
```

It means that product was made on September 23 in 2020 and the .01 could be ignored.

- I need to extract the date in a new cell : 2020/09/23
- I need to compute the date diff between the computed date and today

Is it possible? Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is always in the format shown in your question, you can use [`MID`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mid-midb-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028) to extract the wanted digits from the string, and then put them into [`DATE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349) to output the result as a date. Something like:

```
=DATE(MID($A$1;2;4);MID($A$1;6;2);MID($A$1;8;2))
```

[image]

How the date is displayed can be changed by editing the numberformat of the cell.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively use `Text-To-Columns` in a few steps for your whole column. Note my screenshots would be in Dutch but keep in mind the options would be at the same place for english (or any other language for that matter):

- Select your data
- On the ribbon choose `Text-To-Columns`
- Choose `Fixed-Width`
- Tick lines on position 2 and 9 (see screenshot)

[image]

- Click Next and then for 1st and 3rd column choose to `Skip`.
- On the 2nd column choose `Date` with `YMD` as format.

[image]

That's all.